# Column sortorder when writing CSV file using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net, csv, serialization, csvhelper

When writing TSVs from .Net objects file using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper), I would like to control column sort order using attributes.
When using the CsvHelper-provided `Index(..)` attribute, I am able to control serialization order, but the column header is suffixed with an index:

Model(s), inherited:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic daily data
    /// </summary>
    public class DailyData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(-2, -2)]
        public int IdDay {get;set;}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic hou-on-a-day data
    /// </summary>
    public class HourlyData : DailyData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(-1)]
        public byte IdHour { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class HourlyWeatherInfo : HourlyData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public double Temperature { get; internal set; }
    }
```

Output:

```
IdDay1  IdHour1 Temperature
20220516    18  291.7
20220516    21  289.55
20220517    0   287.3
20220517    3   286.33
```

I am using negative numbers for indices because I want the base class to have their properties listed first without having to bother with serialization order in the derived classes (like `HourlyWeatherInfo`.

Am I overlooking functionality?

Comment: Why do you use negative numbers for indices?  If I use positive numbers everything is OK: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BNIn6A,   Only negative indices seem to cause problems, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/2UNTkk

Comment: Thanks for the example!
I want the base class to have their properties listed first without having to bother with serialization order in the derived classes (like `HourlyWeatherInfo`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels a bit hacky, but this seems to work.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic daily data
    /// </summary>
    public class DailyData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(-2,-3)]
        public int IdDay {get;set;}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic hou-on-a-day data
    /// </summary>
    public class HourlyData : DailyData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(-1,-2)]
        public byte IdHour { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class HourlyWeatherInfo : HourlyData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public double Temperature { get; internal set; }
    }
```

Comment: I was already comfortable somewhat with the hacky feeling, but this works! Thank you!
This kind of behaviour should be covered by a test on my end to guarantee that is keeps working after CsvHelder upgrades.